# How do I calculate values for Gamma function with complex arguments?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, gamma-function

I can calculate the values of Gamma function for positive integer arguments using the formula $\Gamma (t) = \displaystyle\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x} x ^  {t-1} \mathrm{d}x $. Which is equal to $ (t-1)! $. But I don't know how to calculate values for $ \Gamma (a+bi) $. Say, for example, how do I calculate $ \Gamma (1+i) $?

Comment: buzzword: analytic continuiation

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/?title=Gamma_function.

Comment: Start with $i!=\displaystyle\int_0^\infty x^i~e^{-x}~dx$, and then use $x^i=e^{i\ln x}=\cos\ln x+i\sin\ln x$.

Answer (score 2):

You can start using the asymptotic development (Stirling series)$$\log\big(\Gamma(x)\big)=x (\log (x)-1)+\frac{1}{2} \left(\log (2 \pi
   )-\log(x)\right)+\frac{1}{12 x}-\frac{1}{360 x^3}+\frac{1}{1260 x^5}-\frac{1}{1680
   x^7}+$$ $$\frac{1}{1188 x^9}-\frac{691}{360360 x^{11}}+\frac{1}{156
   x^{13}}-\frac{3617}{122400 x^{15}}+\frac{43867}{244188 x^{17}}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{35/2}\right)$$ and use the fact that $x$ is a complex number.

For example, this expansion gives $$\log\big(\Gamma(3+2i)\big)=-0.03163905938061+2.02219319752573 i$$ while the "exact" value (as given by a CAS) would be $$\approx -0.03163905937396 + 2.02219319750133 i$$ So, the expansion would lead to $$\Gamma(3+2i)=-0.422637286329669 + 0.871814255680394 i$$ for an "exact" value (as given by a CAS) $$\approx -0.422637286311202 + 0.871814255696507 i$$ For sure, you could have more terms for the expansion.

Comment: What do you mean by CAS?

Comment: @KYHSGeekCode. **C**omputer **A**lgebra **S**ystem such as Mathematica, Wolfram Alpha and many other.

Comment: Aha, thank you!

Comment: Warning: as the Stirling series is non-convergent, simply adding additional terms will not necessarily improve accuracy here. In particular, you should always cut off the series if the terms start to grow (in modulus) for your value of x. A potentially more effective way of gaining accuracy is to use $\log\Gamma(z) = \log\Gamma(z+1) - \log z$ to increase the modulus of the point at which you compute $\log\Gamma$ by this series. In the example given, if you compute $\log\Gamma(5+2i)-\log(4+2i)-\log(3+2i)$ using just the above terms, you recover the "exact" values referenced from CASes.